# Can't open marker windows using markers tag in angular-google-maps

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

**Aim**
Show a bunch of random markers on a map. Open an info window when one of them is clicked.
I used one of the examples from the API page (markers) and added the markup for a window and a click handler method to show the window. I just can't get it to work however

**Problem**
The markers are displayed, but no window is shown on click.

**Aside**
I had this working when using  tag and ng-repeat; but the docs say the  tag is the preferred method.

Any ideas?

Example here: https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api

Plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ze7EKMQNV7MLGkmlhiAC

```
  <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
      <markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" click="'onClicked'">
        <window ng-cloak show="'showWindow'">
          <h1>{{title}}!</h1>
        </window>
      </markers>
    </google-map>
  </div>

 $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $scope.map.bounds;
    }, function(nv, ov) {
      // Only need to regenerate once
      if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          markers.push(createRandomMarker(i, $scope.map.bounds))
        }
        for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
          var marker = markers[y];
          marker.onClicked = function() {
            marker.showWindow = true;
          }
        }

        $scope.randomMarkers = markers;
      }
    }, true);
```

**Resolved**
This was resolved using the plunk linked to by nitewulf50.

Some notes:

It would appear that the Window tag can only have one child. So I needed to enclose all content within a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows and Window seem like they are tricky to get working as you would want them too.  I had an issue with Windows a few days ago and was given a solution using Window as posted by cthrax on github:

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/633

hope that helps you too.

Comment: This helped me sort it out thanks. Updated the plunk.

Comment: The plunk listed is broken